# How can I improve the speed of processing data from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I am monitoring player activity on a server by logging who is online every minute. The list of  players is stored as a single comma separated string in a varchar field.

I let the player choose a date to display who was online during that day and month.

The script works well and does what it is supposed to except that it takes a long time to process the data the way I am doing it. At the moment about 10 seconds for the page to load.

My question is: is there a more efficient and faster way of getting and displaying the data?

[This is the webpage](http://dcpmc.co.uk/activity.php) that displays player activity.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $chosenDay   =$_POST['day'];
    $chosenMonth =$_POST['month'];
    $chosenYear  =$_POST['year'];
    ?>
<article id="intro">
    <div id="motd">
    <h2>Player Activity Graph</h2>
    <form class="form" action="activity.php" method="POST">
    <select name="year" class="date-select">
    <?php
        echo '<option value="'.$chosenYear.'" selected>'.$chosenYear.'</option>';
        for($i = 2013; $i<$currentYear; $i++){
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
    ?>

    </select>
    <select name="month" class="date-select">
    <?php
        echo '<option value="'.$chosenMonth.'" selected>'.$chosenMonth.'</option>';
        for($i = 1; $i<12; $i++){
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <select name="day" class="date-select">
    <?php
        echo '<option value="'.$chosenDay.'" selected>'.$chosenDay.'</option>';
        for($i = 1; $i<=$days_in_month; $i++){
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="activitysubmit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>

    <p>Please select a date and press submit. You will be presented with a<br /> graph of player activity. Hover over a bar to view the players online at<br /> that time.</p><br /><br />


    <?php
    $chosenDate  =$chosenYear.'-'.$chosenMonth.'-'.$chosenDay;

    $get = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM dcpmc_players_online WHERE date=?");
    $get->bindParam(1, $chosenDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $get->execute();
    $result = $get->fetchAll();
    if(count($result) > 0 ){


        $left = 0;
        echo '<div class="chartWrapper">';
        echo '<p>Players online today</p>';
        echo '<div class="sidelegend"><p>Player count</p></div>';
        echo '<div class="bottomlegend">
        <div class="time"><p>0</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>1</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>2</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>3</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>4</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>5</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>6</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>7</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>8</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>9</p></div>    
        <div class="time"><p>10</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>11</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>12</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>13</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>14</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>15</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>16</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>17</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>18</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>19</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>20</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>21</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>22</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>23</p></div>   
        <div class="time"><p>24</p></div>   
        </div>';
        echo '<div class="bottomlegend2"><p>Time in GMT</p></div>';
        // loop through every hour of today
        for($h = 0; $h<=$hours; $h++){

            // add a zero in front of the first 9 hours
            if($h < 10){$h='0'.$h;}

            // loop through every minute of this hour
            for($m = 0; $m<=$minutes; $m++){

                // add a zero in front of the first 9 minutes
                if($m == 0){$m = '0'.$m;}

                if($m == 00 || $m == 15 || $m == 30 || $m == 45){
                    // build current time to check for players
                    $thisTime = $h.':'.$m.':00';

                    // get players online at this time in this hour of chosen date
                    $get = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM dcpmc_players_online WHERE time=? AND date=?");
                    $get->bindParam(1, $thisTime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $get->bindParam(2, $chosenDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $get->execute();
                    $now = $get->fetchAll();
                        if(count($now) > 0){
                            foreach($now AS $index){
                            $hoverDate = $index['time'];
                            $playerExplode = explode(",", $index['players']);
                            if(count($playerExplode == 1)){
                                foreach($playerExplode AS $index){
                                    if($index == 'none'){
                                        $playerCount = 0;
                                    }else{
                                        $playerCount = count($playerExplode);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            $left = $left+5;
                            $barHeight = $playerCount * 8; // 200px high container / 50 players = 8px per 1 player
                            echo '<div class="barContainer"><div class="bar1" style="height:'.$barHeight.'px;left:'.$left.'px;"></div>';

                            echo '<div class="hoverInfo"><p>'.$hoverDate.'</p><br />';
                            if($playerCount > 0){
                                echo '<p>'.$playerCount.' players online</p><br />';
                                foreach($playerExplode AS $index){
                                    echo '<p>'.$index.' </p>';
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo '<p>No players online.</p>';
                            }


                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            }

                        }
```

As you can see I am using `for` loops to iterate through each minute of each hour, which I am assuming is causing the long delay.

The structure of the Database table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Has you set an index on the date field?

Comment: No I have set primary key as user id

Comment: You are running this query 60 times or more, it seems: `SELECT * FROM dcpmc_players_online WHERE time=? AND date=?`. You can instead grab all the rows (in one query) between two time ranges and then loop on the received data.

Comment: @degenerate Could you show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Baring in mind I am building a bar chart simultaneously for a graphical interpretation of online player numbers.

Comment: Outside the loop do `SELECT * FROM dcpmc_players_online WHERE date=?`, which will select all rows with that date. Then loop through each row and create your bar charts. The way you have it now, you are looping on each minute of the day and searching the database for that. Let the database do the work for you by returning all the dates and times (then loop on that data instead). Your code is too messy for me to specifically help but good luck. I would start from scratch with a table called `players` (id, name) and a table called `plays` (id, TIMESTAMP, playerid). Look up MySQL JOIN tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do, namely replacing * in your SELECT with only the fields that matter to the viewer.

You could also build the database entries to write an 'entry record' when the player logs on and an 'exit record' when they log off.  That way, you're only grabbing two records per session rather than 1 per minute per players online.  You can then adjust your SELECT to calculate whether the person had an entry record for that day and just return a 'yes' value.  Similarly, you could have the PHP find the session entry and exit record and show all kinds of info for that session.

If you want to be certain that they were on and didn't disconnect, then you could also do the check every minute as you are now, and if they are not on the server but their last entry was a login, manually enter a logout record, because they were likely disconnected and the record wasn't created.

I would also suggest adding session ids that are assigned to each entry and exit to make all the calculations easier.